# Cakephp Uploaded on a subdirectory is giving issues

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I just completed a cakephp project with cake 2.x locally , every thing works perfectly.

Now, I moved it online and uploaded to a sub directory, http://doubleedgetechnologies.com.ng/unlimitedgrace/

but below is the error I am getting, I know is .htaccess issue, I have struggled with it for over 3 hours all to no avail.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@doubleedgetechnologies.com.ng and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved it to another server, and it works perfectly there.